# How to Implement security login and logout in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Please go through the following code:

I have been using the following class to authenticate the user:

```
    @Controller
    public class AdminLoginController
    {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/loginForm", method ={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
           public String showForm(ModelMap model) 
           {
    return  GlobalConstants.LOGIN_PAGE;}


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login" ,method ={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm")AdminLoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result , HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
    {

try{
AdminLoginWorker worker=new AdminLoginWorker();
        boolean status=worker.validateUser(loginForm);
if(status)
        {
if("superAdmin".equalsIgnoreCase(loginForm.getUserType()))
                {               
                    dtoBean.setEmp_id(loginForm.getUserName());
                    session.setAttribute("dtoBean", dtoBean);
                    return GlobalConstants.SUPERADMIN_HOME_PAGE;
                }

                if("Admin".equalsIgnoreCase(loginForm.getUserType()))
                {
                    dtoBean.setEmp_id(loginForm.getUserName());
                    session.setAttribute("dtoBean", dtoBean);
                    return GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE;
                }
}catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return GlobalConstants.LOGIN_PAGE;
    }
```

and for the logout:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method ={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
       public ModelAndView logoutForm(HttpServletRequest request) 
       {

         HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            session.invalidate();
        return new ModelAndView( GlobalConstants.LOGIN_PAGE);
       }
```

I called the DAO method to validate from database using:

```
    public class AdminLoginWorker{
    public boolean validateUser(AdminLoginForm loginForm){

        try{    con=DBConnection.getConnection();           
            query="select userType from login where emp_id=? and pwd=?";
                    pstmt.setInt(1,loginForm.getUserName());
            pstmt.setString(2,loginForm.getPassword());
if(rs.next()){               
             loginForm.setUserType(rs.getString(1));
             return true;}
```

so now I wants implement the spring security in my web application so I have tried the following in spring-context.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated"/>  <!-- this  means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->
        <form-login/> <!--  -->
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url=""/>
 </http>
 <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider> 
            <user-service>
                <user name="sachin" password="sachin123" authorities="Admin"/>
            </user-service>
 </authentication-provider>
```

In above security-context.xml file I wants to add data source so that the user will be verified using database so I have been using the below DBCOnnection class for connectivity with Mysql:

```
public class DBConnection {

    private static Connection con=null;
    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        try{
            if(con==null){
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal",
                    "root", "root");
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;
    }
}
```

Now the question i,

How to put the above datasource in security-context.xml file or

Is there any way i can reference from  security-context.xml file to DBConnection class for implementing the spring security login authentication.

does anyone have idea to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are doing of fair amount of wheel reinvention. Everything you are trying to do manually to can easily be handled by Spring Security without writing code, just using the appropriate configuration.

Check out [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/jdbc-user-service-based-spring-security-example/) and [this](http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Spring_MVC_-_Basic_Spring_Security_with_Database) blog post for more details